# catching multiselect values in select box

Tags: php, html

can anyonme give me an idea of how to catch (using PHP) multiple values from a multi 'selectbox' please?

```
<select name="auto_issue_update" multiple>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the name have brackets on the end to distinguish it as an array

```
<select name="auto_issue_update[]" multiple>
```

Then on the PHP side, you would do something like (if you're using POST for your form.  swap POST for GET if you're not)

```
$auto_issue_update = $_POST['auto_issue_update'];
foreach ($auto_issue_update as $a){echo $a.' was selected <br />';}
```

Comment: how do I catch it on the other end ( .php file?)

Comment: sorry for this, but I want to assign the selected values to different variables.

Comment: can you provide a bit more detail in your question.  What variables do you want to assign the results to?  Are there any naming conventions for them?

Comment: What I mean is I have to store these selected values back in the database (MYSQL). So I am not sure how to do that. Assigning the values to variables seems easy to me.

Comment: Again, we need some more information.  What does your database schema look like?  How are you expecting the values to be stored?  1 value per row, values get spread across multiple columns, etc.

Comment: I have a table like this : ID, Selected_Values, Result
So all the <select> values should go into the 'Selected_Values' with some comma imploding. When I extract the values I will use explode to separate them.

Answer (score 3):

define your `select` this way :

```
<select name="auto_issue_update[]" multiple>
```

For PHP, I'm assuming that you POST your form :

```
$myresult = $_POST['auto_issue_update'];
foreach($myresult as $result) { ... }
```