# Why check if value of an array is an array?

Tags: php

I came across the following code in the book PHP Solutions, 2nd Edition

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // assign to temporary variable and strip whitespace if not an array
    $temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);
    // if empty and required, add to $missing array
    if (empty($temp) && in_array($key, $required)) {
        $missing[] = $key;
    } if (in_array($key, $expected)) {
        // otherwise, assign to a variable of the same name as $key
        ${$key} = $temp;
    }
}
?>
```

My question is in regards to this line:

`$temp = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);`

If $value is the value held in the array (user inputted content from a form), why is it critical to determine whether or not the value is an array?  Is it for security?

Answer (score 5):

"why is it critical to determine whether or not the value is an array?"

Because `trim` expects a string and the function might not work when passing an array. It has nothing to do with security.

Comment: beat me to the post:
`PHP Warning:  trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in Command line code on line 1`

Comment: And to clarify, the value could be an array if the input fields had names like `fieldName[]` - you'll commonly see this with multi-select inputs, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728767/catching-multiselect-values-in-select-box

Comment: Thanks everyone!  Makes sense, especially since the trim function is completely unnecessary when dealing with multiple-choice form selections that are NOT written by the user.

Comment: @GP Everything that comes in via the request parameter is a user input and should be handled as such.